# How do I configure sar to collect disk information (ala -d)?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-5

When I run "sar -d" on my RHEL 5.7 box, I get the response:

```
Requested activities not available in file
```

How do I configure sar to collect disk information?

Answer (score 5):

The `sysstat` service which runs the `sa` binaries is not collecting disk statistics in `/var/log/sa` files. This is turned off by default to prevent the logs from growing large on systems with hundreds or thousands of block devices.

When you run `sar` to report disk statistics, the *Requested activities not available in file* message is telling you that `sa` hasn't been collecting disk statistics, so `sar` can't display anything.

You can add config parameters with the `SADC_OPTIONS` value in `/etc/sysconfig/sysstat`

The ability to do this was added in [Bug 598794](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=598794) so you'll need to be running `sysstat-7.0.2-11.el5` or later.

Edit your `/etc/sysconfig/sysstat` file to include a line like:

```
SADC_OPTIONS="-d"
```

then `service sysstat restart`

Give it some time for data to collect (at least 20 minutes), then `sar -d` should work.

Comment: Actually the SADC_OPTIONS are quite different from the command-line options to "sar". The above example of using -d for SADC_OPTIONS is incorrect. Read "man sadc" and note that by default, sadc collects a lot of stuff. The extra options add *additional* areas of statistics to gather, by type.

Answer (score 5):

Read the man page on `sadc` to learn what the various options do in the config file for `sysstat`.  You should see something like:

```
-S { INT | DISK | SNMP | IPV6 | POWER | XDISK | ALL | XALL }
     Specify which optional activities should be collected by sadc.
```

The default in CentOS 6 and CentOS 7 is `-S DISK`, but e.g. I have replaced that with -S SNMP on a box responsible for network monitoring.  You can use multiples like this: `-S DISK -S POWER -S INT`.

Note that you get many statistics by default with `sadc`.  The -S options just add more.

Try something like this to learn how `sadc` and `sar` are related:

```
# /usr/lib64/sa/sadc -S INT -S DISK 10 10 /tmp/test
(... wait 10 * 10 = 100 seconds ...)
# sar -f /tmp/test | head
Linux 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 (icinga02.foo)   11/02/15  _x86_64_   (4 CPU)

15:17:41        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
15:17:51        all     13.94      0.00      2.48      0.03      0.00     83.55
15:18:01        all     14.71      0.00      2.46      0.00      0.00     82.83
15:18:11        all     17.72      0.00      1.88      0.00      0.00     80.40
15:18:21        all     11.47      0.00      1.30      0.00      0.00     87.22
15:18:31        all     18.43      0.00      1.98      0.00      0.00     79.59
```

Note you can extract many other stats from that file now, like `load` instead of `cpu`:

```
# sar -q -f /tmp/test | head
Linux 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 (icinga02.foo)   11/02/15  _x86_64_   (4 CPU)

14:20:01      runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15   blocked
14:30:01            0       239      0.64      0.54      0.50         0
14:40:01            0       240      1.10      1.01      0.74         0
14:50:01            0       242      0.98      0.97      0.84         0
15:00:01            0       243      1.14      0.94      0.88         0
15:10:01            0       242      0.63      0.74      0.82         0
15:20:01            1       244      0.60      0.57      0.68         0
Average:            0       242      0.85      0.80      0.74         0
```